# How to handle chains of "duplicate of..."?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicates

Sometimes one post (P1) is commented "possible duplicate of P2". P2 itself is commented "possible duplicate of P3".

Example:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/246610/how-to-increase-battery-duration-hybrid-graphics-notebook

is pointed to

[Battery drain on ubuntu is fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9817/battery-drain-on-ubuntu-is-fast),

which is a possible duplicate of

[Tips to extend battery life for laptops and notebooks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400/tips-to-extend-battery-life-for-laptops-and-notebooks).

What can/should we do to improve the situation?

Comment: There's tons of these battery life ones on the site, finding them and duping them to the main question would be very helpful!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow the rabbit hole, find the canonical question, comment on each question that is improperly commented, flag each wrong comment for removal, vote to close if you can.

Comment: "vote to close if you can." But these questions are already closed being an exact duplicate...

Answer (score 4):

If the questions are *already closed*, so it's necessary to go through multiple levels of duplicates:

> A [duplicate] **->** B [duplicate] **->** C [duplicate] **->** D [duplicate] **->** E *(master)*

Then:

1. The most serious problem is prevented by the system--the system will not allow a question to be closed as a duplicate under circumstances where it would cause the graph representing the "duplicate of" relation to be cyclic. In other words, questions are never closed as duplicates in a cycle that loops back on itself. There is always some master question. (The master question might *itself* be closed...but not as a duplicate.)
2. This is not *always* bad. Referring to the representation above, sometimes D might make it clear *why* C is really asking something answered by E.
3. This is *often bad* but hardly ever serious, because the problem is easily ameliorated by *commenting on the duplicates further away from the master* to save people the trouble of navigating a long chain.

   For example, if A *should* just have been closed as a duplicate of E, there's no need to reopen and reclose A as a duplicate of E. Instead, just post a short comment on A pointing people to E.